# Upper semicontinuity of fiber dimension for Affine Varieties (reference desired)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties

In [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/418469/counter-example-of-upper-semicontinuity-of-fiber-dimension-in-classical-algebrai) following result is stated:

> If $f : X\to Y$ is a morphism between two irreducible affine varieties over an algebraically closed field $k$, then the function that assigns to each point of $X$ the dimension of the fiber it belongs to is upper semicontinuous on $X$.

I assume that here the author considered by a variety a separate scheme, of finite type over a field.

**Question:** I'm looking for a reference for a proof of this claim. Especially my focus lies on the aspect if the assuption that $k$ is algebraically closed really neccessary or dispensable and I hope that a close inspection of the proof's details would reveal if & how the assumption on algebraic closedness of $k$ in essential way flows in the proof.

Comment: This is true much more often: if $f:X\to Y$ is a locally finite type morphism of schemes, then the function $x\mapsto \dim_x (X_{f(x)})$ is upper semi-continuous. This is EGA IV 13.1.3.

Comment: but this statement works only with *local* dimension $\dim_x(X_{f(x)}) := \inf_{U \subset X_{f(x)} \text{ open nbhd of x }} \dim U$. so that's not a generalization of the claim above.